# Case insensitive autocomplete search (using java, javascript, jquery)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ebean

I have an autocomplete search which is working, but however the problem is that it is case sensitive. I have to type it in the exact format to retrieve the search results.

How do I make it case insenstive? I have searched but cant seem to find solution relating to my specific situation. I am using json for passing data to javascript.

Below is my respective line of code in java for matching the query string. I am using the **contains()** method and finder from ebean play framework.

```
List<Team> teams = Team.find.where().contains("name", query).findList();
```

Any help is much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `ebean` , But i think using case insensitive `contains` will work using `icontains`,

```
List<Team> teams = Team.find.where().icontains("name", query).findList();
```

> icontains
>
> public static Expression icontains(String propertyName,
>                                      String value)
>
> Case insensitive Contains - property like %value%. Typically uses a lower() function to make the expression case insensitive.